# how to run command line commands inside java program and copy the output of console into a file?

Tags: java

```
class cmdln_file {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
            //Process pr = rt.exec("C://apkfiles//new_pro2.apk");

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

            String line=null;

            while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some minor pitfalls with using Process directly, [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) was introduced. Take a look at the example. Not sure about Android though

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear, but if your code runs normally, replace `cmd /c dir` with `cmd /c dir > test.txt`